# Unity2D: Making a cloned particle system fire once only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I a have this enemy prefab that gets instantiated from a spawn point in my game, on the enemy prefab I have a particle system componet that if the player shoots the enemy more than 2 times the particle system will play. However I'm having problems with firing the particle system on only one of the enemy prefab that the player shot. Is there a way when the enemy prefab gets shot at to fire the particle system on that enemy prefab rather than the particle system playing when the enemy prefab gets shoot at and any other enemies prefabs that didn't get shot at without using ontriggerenter2d as I had some problems.

This is the script attached to the player:

```
  public GameObject enemy;
  public static bool firePar = false;
  public static int combo = 0;
  void Start (){
    firePar = false;
    combo = 0;
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
    if(col.tag == "Enemy") {
       Destroy(col.gameObject,0.2f);
     }
  }

  void Update() {
    if(combo >= 10) {
      firePar = true;
    } else if (combo < 10) {
        firePar = false;
    }
  }
```

This is the code on the enemy (for firing the particles):

```
   private ParticleSystem par;

    void Start (){
       par = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    void Update () {
      if(Playerbullet.firePar == true) {  
         par.Play();

       } else {
         par.Stop ();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you have a single particle system for all your enemies and want to trigger it once every time an enemy get shot at, at the enemy position?

Comment: Well that's a shorter way to put it, yes! Thank you!

Comment: Could you add the code you have to kill an enemy and trigger the particles?

Comment: Okay, I have updated my question! The script is above, thank you :)